# Uploading large files using S3TransferManager AWS iOS SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, sdk, multipart

I am trying to upload video from iPhone to AWS S3 using S3TransferManager. It works fine for small files but for larger files I get this error:

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.iossdk.ServiceErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.iossdk.ServiceErrorDomain error 400.)" UserInfo=0x16ed0600 {requestId=856937B6CD6E14DE, exception=AmazonServiceException { RequestId:856937B6CD6E14DE, ErrorCode:InvalidRequest, Message:Key is not expected for the GET method ?uploads subresource }, errorCode=InvalidRequest}
```

To my understanding, S3TransferManager breaks the file into a multipart upload for larger files and something is going wrong then.

My current policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Action":"s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
"Resource":"arn:aws:s3::: my_bucket_name",
"Effect": "Allow"
},
{
"Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl","s3:PutObjectVersionAcl","s3:GetObject","s3:ListMultipartUploadParts","s3:AbortMultipartUpload"],
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"],
"Effect": "Allow"
}
]
}
```

The code to upload is:

```
S3PutObjectRequest *putObjectRequest = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:my_key inBucket: my_bucket_name];
    [putObjectRequest setFilename:videoMetaData.videoFilePath];

    [putObjectRequest addMetadataWithValue:[UserSessionInfo sharedSessionInfo].userEmail forKey:@"email"];
    [putObjectRequest addMetadataWithValue:[UtilHelper formatDuration:videoMetaData.length] forKey:@"videolength"];
    [putObjectRequest addMetadataWithValue:@"Landscape" forKey:@"orientation"];
    [putObjectRequest addMetadataWithValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", data.length] forKey:@"size"];

    putObjectRequest.contentType = @"video/quicktime";
    self.uploadFileOperation = [self.s3TransferManager upload:putObjectRequest];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be missing the permission `s3:GetObjectAcl`?

I also created two separate policies, one for the bucket and another for the content.

Bucket Policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1398382003000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::uploads"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Files Policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1398382057000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::uploads/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I had the same issue, and the above policies worked for me.

Comment: Note, my error was slightly different: `Domain=com.amazonaws.iossdk.ServiceErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.iossdk.ServiceErrorDomain error 403.)" UserInfo=0x188e9450 {requestId=F9E4C8C64994806A, exception=AmazonServiceException { RequestId:F9E4C8C64994806A, ErrorCode:AccessDenied, Message:Access Denied }, errorCode=AccessDenied}`